# Getting all the attributes reachable from a module or any other object

Tags: python

Consider this:

```
>>> import math
>>> dir(math)
['__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'acos', 'acosh', 'asin', 'asinh', 'atan', 'atan2', 'atanh', 'ceil', 'copysign', 'cos', 'cosh', 'degrees', 'e', 'exp', 'fabs', 'factorial', 'floor', 'fmod', 'frexp', 'fsum', 'hypot', 'isinf', 'isnan', 'ldexp', 'log', 'log10', 'log1p', 'modf', 'pi', 'pow', 'radians', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh', 'trunc']
```

`__dict__` is not listed but I can still do

```
>>> math.__dict__
```

Same thing with

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
         def __init__(self, var1, var2):

             self.a = var1
             self.b = var2

         def __call__(self, arg):

             print " The arg passed is ", arg

>>> dir(MyClass) 

['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

`__bases__` and `__base__` is not listed but I can still do:

```
>>> MyClass.__bases__
(<type 'object'>,)
>>> MyClass.__base__
<type 'object'>
```

Question:

How can I know or tell in advance all the attributes reachable from a python object? In this case how can I tell that `math` module has `__dict__` and `MyClass` has `__base__` and `__bases__` ?

Comment: `dir(type(MyClass))` will show them. Metaclass attributes are usually hidden from `dir`. Same thing with `Myclass.mro()`.

Comment: BTW you can define your own `__dir__` method and return random names if you want...

Comment: @JBernardo what is mro() ?

Comment: @JBernardo: `dir(type(MyClass))` will show metaclass attributes which are hidden from `dir(MyClass)`, but it's not a general panacea for showing everything that `dir` hides, just that one case.

Comment: @abc: It stands for Method Resolution Order. I think [Data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) is the docs chapter that describes the `__mro__` property, the `mro` method, and the basics of how the MRO is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something completely general, there is no way to do it, because attribute lookup is dynamic. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) say:

> attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object.

The key word there is "attempt". Down below:

> Note Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

Effectively, all it can do is look at the `__dict__` of the object, its type, and any base classes of the type. (And then it subtracts out a few things—e.g., attributes of the type of the type are skipped to avoid exposing metaclass attributes, which you usually don't care about). If you want the exact details, read the documentation linked above.

Meanwhile, if the object has `__getattr__`/`__setattr__`/`__delattr__`, or `__getattribute__`, or C-API equivalents of the above, it may have all kinds of attributes that aren't in any dictionary, maybe even an infinite set of them. For example:

```
class C(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return name
c = C()
print(c.a)
```

This will print out `a`. But how could `dir` possibly know that `c.a` exists? Even if it could interpret my code, it would have to print out a list of all possible strings, which you obviously don't want.

There are also special attribute names that are handled in fancy ways under the covers by the interpreter.

Also, any object can define a `__dir__` method to return whatever it wants.

If you're looking for something specific, you can probably do that. For example, if you're just trying to get the attributes without subtracting out metaclass attributes, that's just `dir(x) + dir(type(x))`, or, maybe better, `dir(x) + [a for a in dir(type(x)) if a not in dir(x)]` (to remove duplicates).

But if you want to know all attributes for an object, well, you can't.

Comment: If you're curious about this stuff, read [Customizing attribute access](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access), especially the parts about descriptors and slots, and then read about metaclasses (different part of the docs in 2.x and 3.x). If you get through that, you'll have a mental model of how most of the "magic" in Python really works.